# Recursividad en sumatoria

Tags: java, recursión

Este es mi codigo, tengo problemas en el segundo metodo, el cual mediante recursividad debe realizar la sumatoria inversa al metodo sumNumeros
Por ejemplo: suma1N(5);
Entonces seria = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
Me pueden ayudar solo en esa parte porfavor

```
  public class Main{
  public static void main (String[]args){
    System.out.println ("Recursividad");
    System.out.println ("\n" + sumNumeros (4)); //Primera prueba
    System.out.println ("\n" + sumNumeros (5)); //Primer ejercicio
    suma1N(5);//Segundo ejercicio 
    multiplicar(5,10);//Tercer ejercicio
  }
/******************************************************************************/
  public static long sumNumeros (int n){
    if (n == 1){
        System.out.print(n+"=");
    return 1;
    }
    else{
    System.out.print (n + "*");
    return n + sumNumeros (n - 1);
    }
  }//Fin de la prueba

//Comienzo del segundo ejercicio
/******************************************************************************/
     //método recursivo para calcular la suma desde 1 hasta N
     public static long suma1N(int n){
           if(n>0){
               System.out.println(n+"=");
               return 1;
           }else{
               System.out.println(n+"+");
           return n - suma1N(n+1);
        }
     }//Fin del segundo metodo 
//Fin del segundo ejercicio 
/******************************************************************************/
  //Comienzo del tercer ejercicio 
  public static void multiplicar (int iTabla, int iNumero){
    if (iNumero > 1)
      multiplicar (iTabla, iNumero - 1);
    System.out.println (iTabla + "x" + iNumero + "=" + iTabla * iNumero);
  }//Fin del metodo de las tablas
}
```

Comment: Si vas de 1 a n.. cual es la condicion de corte? solo arreglando eso, podras pensar mejor la funcion....

Comment: Tu problema está en el output del método `suma1N()`??

Comment: la sumatoria debe ser como el ejemplo que expusiste, es decir suma1N(5); Entonces seria = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15 o también se permite hacer la sumatoria con los números invertidos es decir suma1N(5); Entonces seria = 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al realizar la **suma recursiva**, ejemplo `sumNumeros(5)`
5+4+3+2+1=15
Podemos observar que sólo necesita un parámetro debido a que la cota inferior es 1.

En cambio para hallar la **suma recursiva inversa** necesitaremos de los parámetros (cota superior y cota inferior), ejemplo `suma1N(5,1)`
1+2+3+4+5=15 Hacemos esto debido a que comienza en 1 pero no sabemos hasta que número tiene que realizar la suma, al tener 2 parámetros ya estaríamos definiendo nuestro límite superior.

El código para la suma recursiva inversa quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
public static long suma1N(int n, int i){          
        if(n==i){
            System.out.print(n+"=");
               return i;
        }else{
            System.out.print(i+"+");             
            return i + suma1N(n,i+1);            
        }        
    }
```

Modificando un poco el método main para tener una mejor visualización de los resultados.

```
public static void main (String[]args){      
        System.out.println ("Suma Recursiva");        
        System.out.println (sumNumeros (5)); 
        System.out.println("Suma Recursiva Inversa");
        System.out.println(suma1N(5,1)); 
}
```

**Salida**

```
Suma Recursiva
5+4+3+2+1=15
Suma Recursiva Inversa
1+2+3+4+5=15
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparto el código que he implementado, basandome en como muestras enconsola y en 2 formas la sumatoria.

Comprendo que solicitaste apoyo con el ejercicio 2 para que se haga la sumatoria desde 1 hasta el valor N que es el que se pasa por parametro. Pero de igual manera te comparto la función funcionando de 1 hasta N y de N hasta 1.

En tu metodo main, modificamos la funcion `suma1N` para que mande 3 parámetros en total.

`Parametro 1:` Es el valor N que contiene el tope de la sumatoria
`Parametro 2:` Es el valor i que se usa para incrementarlo hasta llegar al valor de N y en medio del proceso se muestre en la terminal la sumatoria realizada.
`Parametro 3:` Es el valor suma, este se encarga de realizar la sumatoria con los valores de i en la recursividad y se retorna como resultado final.

---

Para la forma 2 que implementé es inversa, solo se requirieron 2 parámetros en total y la funcion la llamé `sumaN1`

`Parametro 1:` Es el valor N que contiene el tope de la sumatoria. También se usa para reducirlo hasta llegar al valor 1
`Parametro 2:` Es el valor suma, este se encarga de realizar la sumatoria con los valores de N en la recursividad y se retorna como resultado final.

A continuación el llamado de las funciones en el metodo `main`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println ("Recursividad");
    System.out.println("\n" + sumaN1(5, 0));//Segundo ejercicio forma inversa de N a 1
    System.out.println("\n" + suma1N(5, 0, 0));//Segundo ejercicio forma solicitada de 1 a N
    multiplicar(5,10);//Tercer ejercicio
}
```

A continuación la funcionalidad de la función inversa compartida por si le interesa

```
//método recursivo para calcular la suma desde N hasta 1
public static long sumaN1(int n, long suma){
    if(n > 1) {
        System.out.print (n + "+");
        suma += n;
        n--;
        return sumaN1(n, suma);
    } else {
        suma += n;
        System.out.print(n + "=");
        return suma;
    }
}//Fin del segundo metodo
```

A continuación la función del segundo ejercicio que se solicitó

```
// Segunda forma
// método recursivo para calcular la suma desde 1 hasta N
public static long suma1N(int n, int i, long suma){
    if(n > 1) {
        i++;
        System.out.print (i + "+");
        suma += i;
        n--;
        return suma1N(n, i, suma);
    } else {
        i++;
        suma += i;
        System.out.print(i + "=");
        return suma;
    }
}//Fin del segundo metodo
```

Es pero te sirva, saludos.